# why the database table TABLES.table_rows column does not match select count(*) from the physical table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, count, information-schema

When comparing the information_schema.TABLES.table_rows column to the physical row count retrieved from the "SELECT count(*) from " the numbers do not match. Why are the row counts different?

```
mysql> select TABLE_ROWS from TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'gbl_session' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb';
+------------+
| TABLE_ROWS |
+------------+
|       7306 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from mydb.gbl_session;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     7800 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: There were no users or transactions on the system. And I ran "analyze table mydb.gbl_session" prior to running the query.   Server version: 5.6.23-log MySQL Community Server.

Answer (score 1):

> For InnoDB tables, the row count is only a rough estimate used in SQL optimization. (This is also true if the InnoDB table is partitioned.)

Read this for more information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html

As a comment over there suggests, you can try to:

> TABLE_ROWS (and perhaps some other columns in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES) may get out of sync with the current table contents, but you can update it by running ANALYZE.

Comment: I saw all this information on the reference page, but even after running "analyze" the counts do not match. Maybe this Is something that has always been inconsistent with MySQL. But the real question is "Which number is correct?"

Comment: I always go with `select count()`. So far, it hasn't let me down.

Comment: `select count(*)` will be accurate.

Comment: Have always used count(*) and was looking for an alternative or perhaps "better" way to get this information because selecting a single integer column from a cached and indexed table is quicker than using the SQL engine to count the number of rows in the table.

Comment: There's no better option. `SELECT count(1)` may be prettier. Found some nice answers about `count` here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-select-count-and-select-countany-non-null-col